# Error on installing any module in DotNetNuke 5.6.3

Tags: iis-7.5, dotnetnuke

When I upload *any* module in System->Extensions in DotNetNuke 5.6.3, running on a Windows 2008 R2 server, IIS 7.5, after the correct module information is displayed and I hit *next*, I receive the error message

> Message: DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.FieldEditorControl.CreateEditor()at DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.FieldEditorControl.DataBind()at
>   DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.PropertyEditorControl.AddFields(Table tbl)at
>   DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.PropertyEditorControl.CreateEditor() 
>   [...]

and the module is not installed. The file system of the web has not been touched, so I thought it was a permission problem, but even allowing user *Everyone* to do everything doesn't help (after making sure the ApplicationPoolIdentity user has been allowed full access as well).

Any hint is appreciated.
The manifest of the module is valid (it's Dynamic Registration 4.1).

**Update:** Installation steps (*note*: I am using a German installation of Windows 2008, so some translations might not be accurate)

1. Log in as Hosts Super User (Admin)
2. Either navigate to *System->Extensions* or *System->Module Definitions* (*System* might be identical to *Hosts*) - I tried both
3. In *System->Extensions*, click *Installation assistant for extensions*
4. Select file to upload
5. Click *next*
6. Description of uploading package appears correctly - click *next*
7. Error message *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* appears on top of the page. Log View shows stack trace as partly displayed above.

What can cause an error in *DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.FieldEditorControl.CreateEditor()*?

What kind of permissions could be missing?

**Update 2:** By step-by-step debugging, I found out that the view state is broken, for some reason. The method BindPackage() in DesktopModules\Admin\Extensions\Install.aspx.vb doesn't find the current Installer Package. I have not yet found out why the viewstate breaks. It is enabled and huge in the rendered page source.

Comment: Olaf, could you please describe the specific steps you are taking to install the module? There's a few different module installation "paths". Thanks

Comment: @hamlin11: Thanks for looking into this. I added the installation steps.

Comment: Have you possibly added any new profile fields recently?  The error you are getting appears to be coming from the ProfileEditorControl, which is a control that shows profile fields.  I am unsure why the module installation page would be referencing this, but I would definitely check your host and regular user profile fields to see if there are any oddities there.

Comment: @Trillium: Thanks for the hint, but no, I haven't. I'm not too familiar with those fields so I will double-check, maybe compare the fields with those of the standard installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in Update 2, the page's viewstate is lost in  DesktopModules\Admin\Extensions\Install.aspx.vb. Simply replacing ViewState by Session works (but this workaround may be lost after the next DNN update).

**Update** (in case someone has a similar issue):
The DNN container that was used had its viewstate turned off! This results in all kinds of weird behaviour, but it took time to track that error. Now it's obvious.